# Bootstrap: Why isnt my glyphicon showing?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

Edit: I use JSX, where className = class.

I just added some Boostrap to my React component, like this:

```
<div className="col-xs-2">
   <a onClick={this.deleteButtonClicked.bind(this, book)}><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
</div>
```

But the glyphicon does not show up on the page. I am sure I have included Bootstrap in my project correctly, since the grid system works.

This is the generated HTML:

```
<a data-reactid=".0.1:$0.0.1.0"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-reactid=".0.1:$0.0.1.0.0"></span></a>
```

Do you know what the problem is?

Edit 2: Here is the generated CSS

```
box-sizing: border-box
color: rgb(2, 117, 216)
display: inline
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
font-size: 16px
height: auto
line-height: 24px
width: auto
```

Comment: Inspect the span element in the dev tools in your browser and see what styles are being applied.

Comment: Ok, what am I looking for?

Comment: Your HTML looks OK. Use the developer tools of e.g. Chrome to check what the CSS of the rendered span looks like.

Comment: @BjörnBoxstart I don't reallo know what to look for.

Comment: @hellogoodnight you are looking for a `.glyphicon` class in the span styles. The class should be in first in the list. In Google Chrome: inspect element > select the span by clicking on > look at the styles panel.

Comment: @hellogoodnight Because part of bootstrip appears to be working, I expect that the problem is in the availability of the font on your server. Please also see my answer to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet uses your code and the bootstrap CSS and is working. So it must be something in the link to your CSS or the availability of the font (URL is in the CSS). Just including the CSS in your project is not enough if you're using a CSS on your own server. The font also must be available.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a data-reactid=".0.1:$0.0.1.0"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-reactid=".0.1:$0.0.1.0.0"></span></a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, where do I find the font?

Answer (score 0):

the code is working just make sure that you have bootstrap CDN or that you download the css for it